# How to use $scope variable in ng-init

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a $scope variable in controller and I want to access it in DOM in ng-init.

In controller -

```
 $scope.value=true;
```

I want to check or unchecked checkbox based on $scope.value variable. For this I m doing this :

```
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="val" ng-init="val={{value}}">abc
```

but this isn't working...Any solution to this?

Comment: How about `val=value` ?

Comment: I think you abuse ngInit here. Have a look at the [ngInit documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) and you will see, that it would be better to do this in your controller. `$scope.val = $scope.value`

Comment: I have 10 checkboxes and for I need everycheck box to be checked or unchecked based on the $scope variables.

Comment: I think to do what u r saying I need to make a function and call it from ng-init  and include this $scope.val = $scope.value inside the function but that would be hectic to make so many functions,does it mean I have to make function for each checkbox

Comment: val =value is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just assign value in ng-init

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="val" ng-init="val=value">
```

For more information: [angualr ngInit directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)

[See working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pradeep1991singh/Lvc0u55v/2326/)

Comment: Actually this html file is templateURL and the controllerName is already mentioned...still not working

Comment: I tried  ng-model="$scope.value" but this the checkbox is still unchecked..ideally it should be checked as    $scope.value=true

Comment: No sorry i did a typo, please try this `ng-model="value"` :)

Comment: yes that works, but again I am not able to access $scope variables saved in service call in ng-model , if the $scope variable is declared outside service all of this works..any idea about this??

Comment: sure, can you share some code. If possible create a fiddle for the same.

Comment: If your problem you stated in current question is fixed you can accept answer :)

Answer (score 1):

First make sure that you are gave the root dom element in the view as 
ng-controller="controllerName" then try this

```
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="val" ng-init="val=value">abc
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="val" ng-init="val=value">abc
```

hope it helps